# How Can i Extract a Z value of a specific Bitcoin Transaction that Belongs to a merkel tree/root transaction?

Tags: ecdsa, merkle-tree, merkleblock

am trying to find a z value of a transaction that is signed in a merkle tree/root block , i coudn't find a raw tx id in hex  of that specific transaction that signed with  specific address while a raw tx id hex is the hashing of all other addresses in the block , so i couldn't extract Z value from it .. !!!

Comment: What is a "z value" ?

Comment: @PieterWuille Hash of the message ( m )